# mbstowcs Returns -1 on Red Hat Linux But Not on Solaris

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

Our servers were originally made to run on Solaris. We've been making changes so it can run on Linux (current environment is Red Hat Linux), and for some reason `mbstowcs` isn't working. I've confirmed at least two places in the code, one being this:

```
template<class ParamType>
CLStatus Convert(const ParamType &xParam, std::wstring &xStr)
{
    std::stringstream strStream;
    strStream.str("");
    strStream << xParam;
    size_t length = mbstowcs(NULL, strStream.str().c_str(), 0);
    wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[length + 1];
    mbstowcs(buffer, strStream.str().c_str(), length);
```

If `xParam` contains diacritics, then `length` ends up being -1. This same code works on Solaris, but not Linux. Anyone have any ideas?

I looked to see if they're using different locales, but both are using `LC_ALL="en_US"`

Comment: I don't know much about Red Hat configurations, but you should check to see if your default character set is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-x (x is usually 1 or 15). If it's the latter, then mbstowcs will report invalid multibyte characters for utf-8 encoding (and similarly, if the character set is utf-8 and iso-8859-15 codes greater than 0x7f are found.)

Comment: What's the default encoding for `"en_US"`?  (You might try `"en_US.UTF-8"` under Linux.)

Comment: I've tried both `LC_ALL="en_US.ISO8859-1"` and `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`, both result in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do before trying to use UTF-8 multibyte strings:

```
static int mbr_utf8_init() {
  if (NULL == setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")
      || 0 != strcmp(nl_langinfo(CODESET), "UTF-8")) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "%s\n",
            "Unable to use UTF-8; trying changing LANG to a Unicode locale");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you don't call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`, then you stay in the "C" locale set up at program initialization, regardless of the setting of any environment variable. `""` as the second argument of `setlocale` means "use the locale specified by environment variables"; you could force the locale to a specific value if you wanted to. (There are many things which suck about the standard C locale interface; one of them is that character encoding is considered to be part of the locale, rather than the string type. This makes in annoying to handle files of different encodings. But I digress.)

On Linux, the C locale doesn't like characters outside of the basic character set. Solaris might be different.

With the above code, the locale set in the environment (or at least the LC_CTYPE) must correspond with the encoding of string. If you're not using UTF-8 strings, you'll need some other `nl_langinfo` check